# Set custom margin for the res class

Tags: fontsize, width, cv, resume

I am trying to make my resume using the `res` class.

the problem that I am facing is with the page borders. How I do I set in acc

**Here is what My `.tex` file looks like**

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[margin, centered, 11pt]{res}
\topmargin=-0.5in
\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.5in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
\newsectionwidth{1in}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = black,
            urlcolor  = black,
            citecolor = black,
            anchorcolor = black]{hyperref}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in} % Text width of the document
\setlength{\textheight}{720pt}
\newcommand{\ts}{\textsuperscript}

\begin{document}

%------------------------------------------------------------------
% ACHIEVEMENT SECTION
%------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Achievements \& Awards}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
  \item \href{https://plino.herokuapp.com/}{Plino} got featured on \href{https://www.producthunt.com/tech/plino}{\emph{Product Hunt}} in \textbf{tech} genre.
  \item Senior Member of the College Coding Club, \textbf{Code Rumble}
\end{itemize}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

I am getting something like this

[image: output]

What I want to do is shift the left and right border ( if that's what its called) equally on each sides so that there is no overlap like this. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

**EDIT**

One way I got past this problem was to do a

```
\newsectionwidth{1.15in}
```

and

```
\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width 19.5cm height 0.5pt}
```

But there obviously must be a better way